# Web Service request in PHP

Tags: php

I am starting to learn PHP by messing around with the wunderground API.

I have the below code sample from them that works locally when testing with xanampp/apache but when I put it on an actual live web server on the internet it doesnt seem to be making the call to the web service.

Code:

```
<?php
  $json_string = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/key/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json");
  $parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
  $location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
  $temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
  echo "Current temperature in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";


?>
```

Results Locally on my machine with xampp:

```
Current temperature in Cedar Rapids is: 77.4
```

Results on webserver that I pay to host pages:

```
Current temperature in is:
```

Error report:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b2414/ipg.domainID/testt.php on line 5 Warning: file_get_contents(http://api.wunderground.com/api/key/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b2414/ipg.domainID/testt.php on line 5 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b2414/ipg.domainID/testt.php on line 7 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b2414/ipg.domainID/testt.php on line 7 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b2414/ipg.domainID/testt.php on line 8 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /hermes/bosnaweb01b/b2414/ipg.domainID/testt.php on line 8 Current temperatdure in is:
```

Comment: what does : `echo "Current temperature in ".$location." is:". $temp_f."\n";` say ?

Comment: Have you enabled full error reporting? The most likely cause it your json can't be retrieved (either because `allow_url_fopen` is disabled, or there may be other issues.

Comment: @Wrikken not sure how to enable error reporting. This is admittedly my first night working with PHP. Do have some experience with web services but not with php

Comment: You can find how to enable error reporting in the [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info), under _"I have a typical "does not work" problem. What should I do before asking a question?"_ (Don't take that as a criticism of me personally, that's just how that section is called :) )

Comment: Use curl instead and you will do it without changing php configurations

Comment: @Wrikken cool! Thank you. Got it to work adding error report to post.

Comment: Are you in control of those hosting settings, or are you using a 3rd party that set this up for you? In case of the latter, I'd ask for a non-crippled PHP-setup please :P (In other words: ask them to enable this).

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Web servers do not allow file_get_contents often. Using curl:

```
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "http://api.wunderground.com/api/key/geolookup/conditions/q/IA/Cedar_Rapids.json",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Codular Sample cURL Request'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

$json_string = $resp;
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
  $location = $parsed_json->{'location'}->{'city'};
  $temp_f = $parsed_json->{'current_observation'}->{'temp_f'};
  echo "Current temperatdure in ${location} is: ${temp_f}\n";
```

Comment: This is an alternative, not an "answer" to the question. It could even be equally likely that the web servers do not allow cURL often.

Comment: @scrowler But if this the only to do what i want in my environment and there is no way to do it using file_get_contents without server changes to php.ini does that mean this is a question that cam never be answered?